# Between numerical values with no lower limit in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My data looks something similar to:

| days | weight | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 180 | 1 | 01/01/2020 | null |
| 365 | 0.75 | 01/01/2020 | null |

And I want to be able to select this to assign the correct value where say if the days were 0-180, they would be row 1 and 181-365 it would be row 2. If it was 365+ it would be row 2. I have already found out I can use between sql syntax for the date.

My initial code tries to do this:

```
select weight from (select * from table where days >= @DAYS order by days ASC) where rownum =1
```

But then if you do more than the last value it doesn't show anything so i've then tried to introduce a maximum element trying to find the maximum value and saying

```
>= @DAYS
or 
>= MAX(@DAYS)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you want when it is more than the max value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Linoff pick the largest number it can.

Comment: In that case your table data is inappropriate. It holds the maximum number of days for which a weight applies. If there are intervals that are not covered by the table, then no weight applies. It's as simple as that. Add an entry with an extreme days number, if you want to apply a weight to those longer intervals.

Comment: Simply, row 2 does not exists

Comment: Using `ROWNUM` for this is specific to Oracle by the way, and they even violate the SQL standard in order to make this work (because in standard SQL a subquery result is considered unordered). You can work with `MAX OVER`, `ROW_NUMBER OVER` or `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to get this standard compliant.

Comment: An alternative would be not to store the maximum number of days for which a weight applies, but the minimum value. Thus greater numbers of days would be implicitely covered by the last row. (And only zero days or a negative day number would probably have no entry, but I guess these shouldn't have one, anyway.)

Comment: What is that *value* which you want to assign (to what?)? There are 4 columns where one column has some days that you mentioned in your question (looks like you need to compare something with it). However, what the dates are? What the weight is? What should be the output for which input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select weight
from (select t.*, max(days) over () as max_day from table t) v
where days >= least(@DAY,max_day) 
order by days asc
fetch first 1 row only
```

I'd suggest this option. When `@DAY` becomes larger than the largest `days` entry, we use max_days instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select max(weight) from table
Where days=(Select max(days) from table
            Where days >= @DAYS)
```

The first max() function is defensive in case your table has 2 entries with the same days number.

Comment: In Oracle we would usually write this as `select max(weight) keep (dense_rank last order by days) from table where days >= :DAYS;` But however we write this, this doesn't solve the origiinal problem when there is no row matching `days >= :DAYS`.